# Add authentication mechanism to Java Jersey restful webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I am using **Java jersey Restful webservice**. 

How can I add **authenication mechanism** to this jersey webservice, Once its authenticated I need to ratain the session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a filter to your Jersey server that carries out authentication.  Jersey provide one using Basic authentication as `HttpBasicAuthFilter`, and there are lots of other examples out there on the 'net using different authentication schemes.

You should not use sessions with REST, as it creates a link between multiple requests over time; every REST request should be standalone and not rely on anything that has happened previously.  Each REST request should have its own authentication parameters.